# Having issue in Android Localization

Tags: android, localization, locale

I've taken reference form all well-suggested blogs to implement **Localization in Android**, But still, it is not working in my app

- **res folder**

[image]

- **libraries used in build.gradle**[image]

**- method for changing Locale**

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**- Using Custom Font (Lato)**

```
public static void overrideFont(Context context,
                                String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
    try {
        final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

        final java.lang.reflect.Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

calling this method from Application Class

```
overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF",
            GlobleConstant.LATO_REGULAR);
```

**Assets Folder**

[image]

**Don't know what's wrong in above code please somebody help.
Tested Devices - Nexus 5x , Xiaomi 3s prime**

Comment: how you set text to textview?

Comment: In method setLocale(...), how to get getIntent();

Comment: @LalitJadav yes I've set text to TextView using getString(R.string.id)

Comment: @ChetanPushpad setLocale(...) method is inside Activity so u can call getIntent() directly.